# odoo 15 hr_zk_attendence gives "ValueError: Wrong value for zk.machine.attendance.punch_type: '255'"

Tags: valueerror

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
result = request.dispatch()
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\http.py", line 698, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\http.py", line 368, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\http.py", line 357, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\http.py", line 921, in **call**
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\http.py", line 546, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "c:\users\admin\desktop\odoo\new\odoo-15.0\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1328, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "c:\users\admin\desktop\odoo\new\odoo-15.0\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1316, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\api.py", line 464, in call_kw
result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\api.py", line 451, in _call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\admin\desktop\odoo\new\odoo-15.0\custom_addons\hr_zk_attendance\models\zk_machine.py", line 166, in download_attendance
zk_attendance.create({'employee_id': get_user_id.id,
File "", line 2, in create
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\api.py", line 412, in _model_create_multi
return create(self, [arg])
File "c:\users\admin\desktop\odoo\new\odoo-15.0\addons\hr_attendance\models\hr_attendance.py", line 276, in create
res = super().create(vals_list)
File "", line 2, in create
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\api.py", line 413, in _model_create_multi
return create(self, arg)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_fields.py", line 613, in create
recs = super().create(vals_list)
File "", line 2, in create
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\api.py", line 413, in _model_create_multi
return create(self, arg)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\models.py", line 4081, in create
records = self._create(data_list)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\models.py", line 4145, in _create
col_val = field.convert_to_column(val, self, stored)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\fields.py", line 2536, in convert_to_column
value = self.convert_to_cache(value, record)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\fields.py", line 2548, in convert_to_cache
raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %r" % (self, value))
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\http.py", line 654, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Odoo\new\odoo-15.0\odoo\http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: Wrong value for zk.machine.attendance.punch_type: '255'

1.How to solve this error. If it needs to change code.which module was changed and which line

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For other people who may come to this question by searching like me.

1. The example is using the Odoo module "hr_zk_attendance".
2. The error occurs because the variable "punch_type" is Selection type and only allows values (0,1,2,3,4,5). You can see it in"models/machine_analysis.py" file.
3. To avoid this error, add in the field punch_type, the value 255 (file models/machine_analysis.py).
4. In the file "zk_machine.py", only creates the register in hr_attendace model if "punch" value is 0 or 1 (check-in or check-out). In this case, is needed to add an else condition with 255 value and manage how the record should behave.